# Expanding HTML forms using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form that asks a user to input their name, SKU, quantity, and comments. This is for a simple inventory request system.

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post"> 
        <input type="submit">
        <br>Name: <input type="text" name="form[name]"> 
        <br>SKU: <input type="text" name="form[SKU1]"> 
        <br>Quantity: <input type="text" name="form[quantity1]">
     <br>Comment: <input type="text" name="form[comment1]"> 
</form> 
<a href="javascript:addOption();">Add item</a> 

<script> 
        var num = 2; //The first option to be added is number 2
        function addOption() { 
                var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); 
                var newOption = document.createElement("input"); 
                newOption.name = "form[SKU"+num+"]"; // form[varX]
                newOption.type = "text";
                theForm.appendChild(newOption); //How can I add a newline here?
                optionNumber++;
        } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I can only get it working where it will add a single form value. I would like to recreate the entire myForm except for the name field with a single click.

Comment: I don't. I just haven't found anything in HTML that will let me create additional forms on demand like this. Could you enlighten me with the HTML version of what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is very old, so presumably you've found an answer by now.  However, there are some things amiss with your code.

In the JavaScript code you have

```
var num = 2;
```

This is the number that is incremented to keep track of how many "line-items" you will have on the form.  In the function addOption(), though, instead of incrementing num you have

```
optionNumber++;
```

You never use optionNumber anywhere else.  Your code works once, when you add the first item, but since you increment the wrong variable, you are effectively always adding option 2.

Oh, and adding the newline:  you need to append a `<br>` element.